# ASP.NET Add a link button to the triggers of an update panel dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, triggers, updatepanel

in an asp.net/C# application

I have an update panel on the page.
How to make a link button force the partial post-back of that update panel without adding it to the

```
<Triggers></Triggers>
```

Tag of the update panel?

The reason I need this is because I am dynamically creating link buttons, so I don't know their number or Id to preset them in the Triggers tag.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2382900/114029

Comment: Would you mind telling us what link from my answer worked for you?

Comment: Thank you for your help this approach worked: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1572561.aspx